# Condition for inequalities

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods

I have a collection of inequalities that I need to find a sufficient condition for:

Let $d\in \mathbb{N}$ and consider natural $k$'s such that $k\geq d+2$. I want to find a condition of the form 
\begin{equation}
 k>C(k,d) \tag{I}
\end{equation}
$k>C(k,d)$ 
for which the following inequalities will hold:

\begin{equation*}
 \begin{aligned}
  C&>\frac{4d\log(k)}{\log(2k-1)-4}\\
  \frac{k}{d}&>e^C \left( 2\sqrt{2k-1}+2\log k+D' \right)  \\
  \frac{1-d}{d}+2\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{d}}&<e^C \left( 2\sqrt{2k-1}+2\log k+D' \right)
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $C$ and $D'$ should be constants not dependent on $k$. This conditions arose naturally for some equations to be true, and I would like to find a somewhat strict condition on $k$ of the form of (I), but have not really had much experience with finding strict solutions for such complicated inequalities. Is there perhaps a standard approach to such a problem that someone can point me to?

Comment: Have you considered a bounty?